# What type of screws and anchors are used for concrete?

Tags: screws, anchor, concrete-block

I have cinder block walls along one side of the garage and hang a lot of 'tool storage' hangers and such. Often what I buy comes with screws and anchors so I use that but I have some hangers I just got for hanging lawn equipment that did not.

I already know a different type of drill bit is used for concrete, and I have those. However if I need to buy some screws and anchors for concrete, and wondered are they different than ones used for drywall? For example if I go to the hardware store and get one of those '150 piece' screw + anchor variety set, are they OK to use in concrete or are there any differences for screws and anchors used in concrete?

Comment: you might post a link to the 150 set in question.  Some might be ok or good for concrete, others not

Comment: I was just speaking generically. So you are inferring that there are indeed differences?

Comment: any of the plastic anchors will work in concrete if the hole is the correct (tight fitting) size.  The screw must 'jam' the anchor against the hole for proper grip.  The expanding anchor class of fasteners do a better job than just a screw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suitablilty of fasteners for supporting bracketry in concrete depends mostly on the weight.

- light duty 0-10lbs: Screws with concrete threads, no anchors needed
  (EG Tapcon and Spax)
- medium duty: 10-50lbs:  anchors of plastic or lead,
- heavy duty:  50+    : sleeve and wedge anchors

There are overlaps between light and medium duty , based on screw size and depth of penetration.  Follow package directions closely.  Drill the exact size hole and depth called for, the fastener retention depends on it!

[image]

Comment: I will probably go for the 'sleeve and wedge anchors' you listed to be on the safe side. Could you please provide a link to a picture of such a thing just so I have an idea what they look like?