# What type of anchor for fastening to block wall?

Tags: anchor, fastener, concrete-block

So, I started with [What type of screws and anchors are used for concrete?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25619/what-type-of-screws-and-anchors-are-used-for-concrete) - but it's not particularly clear to me.

I (hammer) drilled 5/32" holes into an exterior wall for 3/16" tapcon screws. These didn't hold. So now I'm wondering what kind of anchor I should be using -

- Wedge?
- Sleeve?
- Split?

Or can I use a standard plastic anchor I have, assuming it fits properly? I can't seem to wrap  my head around the differences in these "concrete" anchors except that wedge shouldn't be used for block, only solid concrete.

The wall is stucco of minimum depth, then I'm guessing cinder block. It's not brick.

I need to drill in and still have maybe 1/4" sticking out to hang a garden hose mount. So in terms of strength, I just need to hold say a 25 ft garden hose that may or may not be completely full of water.

Comment: Was the hole clean? Did the bit "wander" or end up making a larger hole than the diameter of the bit? This is often the culprit. Or did the fastener fail by sliding and cutting out the material? If you could elaborate on how the fastener failed, especially with pictures that might be helpful.

Comment: I think the tapcons failed because there's not enough material for them to stick to before hitting the air behind the block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With stucco the wall is two thin for tapcon screws, Since you already have a hole I think your best bet is a molly bolt or toggle that expands once inside the wall  fill the hole with calking so no moisture or bugs can find thier way in.

Comment: Toggle bolts FTW. They will probably prove about as sturdy as you will ever get here.

Comment: The thing with toggle bolts are they require a hole big enough for the flanges, which are usually bigger than the bolt. I suppose that's corrected with the caulk?